# CompletableFuture never makes a call to DAO class

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

When i use CompletableFuture to test database connection, the call to DAO class never happens. Thread never completes.

When i try to do the same thing in main thread with direct DAO call to class, it works just fine

**Below code never completes the call**

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        LOG.info("Testing My DB Connection");
        return this.myDBDao.testConnection();
    } catch(SQLException sqlE) {
        return false;
    }
}, this.asyncExecutor).thenAccept(val -> {
        if(val) {
            LOG.info("My DB Connection Test SUCCESS");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("CONNECTION TO MY DB FAILED");
        }
}).join();
```

**Below code works just fine**

```
try {
    if(this.myDBDao.testConnection()) {
        LOG.info("Testing My DB Connection");
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("CONNECTION TO MY DB FAILED");
    }
} catch(SQLException sqlE) {
    throw new RuntimeException("CONNECTION TO MY DB FAILED");
}
```

**DAO Method**

```
private static final String TEST_CON_QUERY = "select 'TRUE' as val from dual";

public boolean testConnection() throws SQLException {
        LOG.info("testConnection from DAO: " + this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query(TEST_CON_QUERY, (rs) -> {
            return (rs.next()) ? rs.getBoolean("VAL") : false;
        });
    }
```

**DataSource and Connection Pool**

```
@Bean(name = "myDBTemplate")
    JdbcTemplate myJDBCTemplate() throws SQLException {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(******);
        config.setUsername(******);
        config.setPassword(******);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
        config.setMinimumIdle(10);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setPoolName("myDBPool");
        return new JdbcTemplate(new HikariDataSource(config));
    }
```

**Executor**

```
@Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public ExecutorService getAsyncExecutor() {
        return Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }
```

*Why is code inside CompletableFuture never able to make call to testConnection() method?*

Comment: I'd wonder why you're doing this at all.  I would recommend a connection pool like Hikari over anything that you or I would write.

Comment: I was just trying a way to reduce time for first query call in application. Trying to add this code at start up. My observation is, once application is up, the first call to database takes more time. I believe it’s the first call when connection pool is setup. Any calls after that are 5x faster.

Comment: The Hikari folks wrote a better connection pool than you ever will.  I'd use that.

Comment: I’d only do what you’re doing if I were paid by the hour, and by lines of code. Otherwise, I’d use one of many battle-tested connection pools out there.

Comment: There is not enough code to reproduce your problem, it could come from anything we wouldn't think of (e.g. how you set up your executor, how you configure the logging…). Could you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: @DidierL i added few blocks of code that i have. i am running this code in Spring Boot application and the testConnection() call is at the start up of the application.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks! i agree. I am actually using HikariCP. What i am trying to do, is just make a query call at the start up of the application(Just to see if i can improve timing on first call to application once its up and running). What i am curious about is why 1 without CompetableFuture work and other one do not.

Comment: `return (rs.next()) ? rs.getBoolean("VAL") : false;` would be more explicit if written like `return rs.next() && rs.getBoolean("VAL");`.

Comment: How do `this.asyncExecutor` and this `getAsyncExecutor()` relate to each other?

Comment: @Holger its a Spring Bean and is Autowired in class

Comment: I understood that this has something to do with Spring, but what does that mean exactly? You create a method `getAsyncExecutor()` that would create a new executor on every invocation (which would be a giant code smell if that method was supposed to be used like an ordinary getter method), then, you define a field `asyncExecutor`, to be filled by Spring’s magic, so it has the same effect as if you declared it as `private final ExecutorService asyncExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`, but just with a lot more code and less knowledge about what actually goes on, did I get it correctly?

Comment: @Horger as I understand it, he declared that in his `@Configuration` class, and it is a singleton. Moreover IIRC this is also how you declare your executor for `@Async`. So this seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Holger by default it is singleton. So, it'll(Spring) create 1 executor at the startup. Every time i do an Autowired, Spring will provide me with the same executor.

Comment: Well, the executor would be the first point to look at, when the code is not executed. But well, is it not executed or does it not complete? (the latter scenario would raise the question whether you database driver actually supports evaluations in a background thread) @DidierL well, I’m not using such frameworks and don’t see the point of writing more complicated code with “magic annotations”, without getting an actual benefit. At least for a [mcve], the code should get rid of things outside our control, to be able to reproduce the problem or to eliminate the framework as the problem.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! i actually tried to add more tasks to the same executor, making an API call and an I/O operation. Both those got completed however, the call to DB did not. i'll try to replicate the same behavior(if i can) without Spring framework as well.

Comment: Worked for me, check out complete project: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa and give a try, sample implementation: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/service/impl/ArticleServiceImpl.java

Comment: once you run the project execute `curl -k 'localhost:8080/56347092/2987755'` on terminal output will be like: `In DAO
Testing, My DB Connection,
My DB Connection Test SUCCESS,
At controller,
Before DAO,
After DAO`